# How to convert R dataframe back to Pandas using rpy2?

Tags: python, r, pandas

I converted a pandas dataframe to R using the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.rpy.common as com
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

rdf = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(df)
```

How do I convert `rdf` back to a `pandas.DataFrame`?

```
df = f(rdf)
```

Comment: `pandas.rpy` was removed in pandas 0.20

Answer (score 33):

Since rpy2 release 2.4.0 converting data frames back and forth between `rpy2` and `pandas` is included as an optional module. With it, no need to convert explicitly, it will be done on the fly.

The documentation contains examples (also available as a Jupyter notebook - link available near the top of the page): 
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/pandas.html#interoperability-with-pandas

**Note:** The original answer to this question recommended the following.

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
```

If wishing to convert explicitly for any reason, the functions are `pandas2ri.py2ri()` and `pandas2ri.ri2py()` (they were `pandas2ri.pandas2ri()` and `pandas2ri.ri2pandas()`).

**Note:** Since rpy2 release 3.3.0 explicit conversion is done as follows

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro

dt = pd.DataFrame()
# To R DataFrame
r_dt = ro.conversion.py2rpy(dt)
# To pandas DataFrame
pd_dt = ro.conversion.rpy2py(r_dt)
```

For more details check out this [link](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/pandas.html).

Comment: I am a noobie to Python. When I use the above functions, I lose my categorical objects and they become integers.

Comment: Any ideas on changing the behaviour? @Igautier

Comment: Which version are you using ? This answer is a bit old (4.5 years), and there were changes in the way factors are converted: https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/commits/29e8a62de897

Comment: Yes Igautier, I got them working. Thanks for replying.

Comment: @lgautier are you aware of the way we should do it now? The answer is a bit old

Comment: @Hiyam the doc pointed by the link is few days old. It is not too old to be used.

Comment: @lgautier, can you please explain how to include the optional import? After much searching how to convert Pandas df to Rdf, it still not works. In my case it seems easiest to include an entire embedded R script like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45325274/calling-r-library-randomforest-from-python-using-rpy2) and [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/bioinformatics/comments/owtcw8/comment/h7lnb2c/); but will I have to convert the df or can I just call it as [you seemingly did](http://lgautier.github.io/odsc-pdaibp-slides/notebooks/slides.html) with a `'""" + dbfilename + """'`?

Answer (score 12):

As suggested by lgautier, it can be done with `pandas2ri`.

Here is sample code for convert rpy dataframe (`rdf`) to pandas dataframe (`pd_df`):

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

pd_df = pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe(rdf)
```

Comment: This operation replaces the index of the R dataframe with integers (if it was something other than integers to begin with). Anyone know how to keep the original index?

Answer (score 9):

Given your import, it appears it is:

```
com.convert_robj(rdf)
```

For example,

```
In [480]: dfrm
Out[480]:
           A          B  C
0   0.454459  49.916767  1
1   0.943284  50.878174  1
2   0.974856  50.335679  2
3   0.776600  50.782104  1
4   0.553895  50.084505  1
5   0.514018  50.719019  2
6   0.915413  50.513962  0
7   0.771571  49.859855  2
8   0.068619  49.409657  0
9   0.728141  50.945174  2
10  0.388115  47.879653  1
11  0.960172  49.680258  0
12  0.015216  50.067968  0
13  0.495024  50.286287  1
14  0.565954  49.909771  1
15  0.992279  49.009696  1
16  0.179934  49.554256  0
17  0.521243  47.854791  0
18  0.551241  51.076262  1
19  0.713271  49.418503  0
20  0.801716  50.660304  1

In [481]: rdfrm = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(dfrm)

In [482]: rdfrm
Out[482]:
<DataFrame - Python:0x14905cf8 / R:0x1600ee98>
[FloatVector, FloatVector, IntVector]
  A: <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.FloatVector'>
  <FloatVector - Python:0xf9d0b00 / R:0x140e2620>
[0.454459, 0.943284, 0.974856, ..., 0.551241, 0.713271, 0.801716]
  B: <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.FloatVector'>
  <FloatVector - Python:0xf9d0878 / R:0x125aa240>
[49.916767, 50.878174, 50.335679, ..., 51.076262, 49.418503, 50.660304]
  C: <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.IntVector'>
  <IntVector - Python:0x11fceef0 / R:0x13f0d918>
[       1,        1,        2, ...,        1,        0,        1]

In [483]: com.convert_robj(rdfrm)
Out[483]:
           A          B  C
0   0.454459  49.916767  1
1   0.943284  50.878174  1
2   0.974856  50.335679  2
3   0.776600  50.782104  1
4   0.553895  50.084505  1
5   0.514018  50.719019  2
6   0.915413  50.513962  0
7   0.771571  49.859855  2
8   0.068619  49.409657  0
9   0.728141  50.945174  2
10  0.388115  47.879653  1
11  0.960172  49.680258  0
12  0.015216  50.067968  0
13  0.495024  50.286287  1
14  0.565954  49.909771  1
15  0.992279  49.009696  1
16  0.179934  49.554256  0
17  0.521243  47.854791  0
18  0.551241  51.076262  1
19  0.713271  49.418503  0
20  0.801716  50.660304  1
```

With docs:

```
In [475]: com.convert_robj?
Type:       function
String Form:<function convert_robj at 0x13e85848>
File:       /mnt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/rpy/common.py
Definition: com.convert_robj(obj, use_pandas=True)
Docstring:
Convert rpy2 object to a pandas-friendly form

Parameters
----------
obj : rpy2 object

Returns
-------
Non-rpy data structure, mix of NumPy and pandas objects
```

Answer (score 6):

Use pandas to read an rpy2 dataframe, `r_df`. It will avoid the deprecation warning "FutureWarning: from_items is deprecated. Use DataFrame.from_dict(dict(items), ...) instead"

`type(r_df)` is "rpy2.robjects.vectors.DataFrame".
`type(pd_df)` is "pandas.core.frame.DataFrame"

`pd_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({ key : np.asarray(r_df.rx2(key)) for key in r_df.names })`

Comment: Above solutions are outdated, but this seemed to work great for latest 3.2.0 version of rpy2.

Comment: preise and works fine with old and new verisions

Comment: This is the only method that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The other solutions seem to be outdated and did not work for me anymore.

From the [docs](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/pandas.html#interoperability-with-pandas), this is the current way to convert data from/to pandas to/from R objects.

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
```

From pandas to R:

```
with (ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter).context():
  r_from_pd_df = ro.conversion.get_conversion().py2rpy(pd_df)

r_from_pd_df
```

From R to pandas:

```
with (ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter).context():
  pd_from_r_df = ro.conversion.get_conversion().rpy2py(r_df)
pd_from_r_df
```

**This only works in rpy2 version `>=3.5.7`.**

Comment: The last example gives me `AttributeError: __enter__` with rpy2 3.5.9.

Answer (score 0):

R script:

```
set.seed(123) 
rows <- 50
cols <- 10
r_data <- matrix(rnorm(rows * cols), nrow = rows)
df_r <- as.data.frame(r_data)
```

Python script:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

def processData():
    with open('[path_to_your_R_script]/example.R', 'r') as file:
        r_script = file.read()    
    with (robjects.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter).context():
        robjects.r(r_script)
        r_dataframe = robjects.globalenv['df_r']
        pd_from_r_df=robjects.conversion.get_conversion().rpy2py(r_dataframe)
```

If you are trying to access R scripts inside Django framework make sure to add the following code to `manage.py` for initializing R from the main thread.

```
import rpy2.rinterface

def main():
    rpy2.rinterface.initr()
```