# Jupyter RMagic doesn't return interactive R output

Tags: python, r, jupyter, rpy2

According to [the `rpy2` docs](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/interactive.html#module-rpy2.ipython.rmagic) it should be possible to see interactive R output like this:

```
%%R
X=c(1,4,5,7)
Y = c(2,4,3,9)
summary(lm(Y~X))
```

Which is supposed to produce this:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X)

Residuals:
    1     2     3     4
 0.88 -0.24 -2.28  1.64

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   0.0800     2.3000   0.035    0.975
X             1.0400     0.4822   2.157    0.164

Residual standard error: 2.088 on 2 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.6993,Adjusted R-squared: 0.549
F-statistic: 4.651 on 1 and 2 DF,  p-value: 0.1638
```

But despite being able to return nice-looking graphs from R using [stuff like this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41889995/2071807), the R interactive output from `summary` is not returned.

I can get round this by doing:

```
In [75]: %%R -o return_value                                                  
       : X = c(1,4,5,7)                                              
       : Y = c(2,4,3,9)                                              
       : return_value = summary(lm(Y~X))
```

Then `print`ing the returned value like this (although the output looks pretty bad because there are blank lines between each output line):

```
In [86]: print(return_value)


Call:

lm(formula = Y ~ X)



Residuals:

    1     2     3     4

 0.88 -0.24 -2.28  1.64



Coefficients:

            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)

(Intercept)   0.0800     2.3000   0.035    0.975

X             1.0400     0.4822   2.157    0.164
```

Are the docs incorrect, or am I doing something wrong?