# Plot data on satellite maps

Tags: python, pandas, google-maps, maps, earthpy

How to plot `(lat, lon, value)` data on a map using satellite background images at high resolution in python (notebooks)?

I was crawling the whole internet but could not find anything useful. [Folium](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium) does not provide satellite tiles. [SimpleKML](https://ocefpaf.github.io/python4oceanographers/blog/2014/03/10/gearth/) and [googleearthplot](https://github.com/AtsushiSakai/googleearthplot) seem only to be useful for huge low-resolution Earth data. [EarthPy](http://earthpy.org/cartopy_backgroung.html) can accept image tiles, but their link to the NASA website only provides low-resolution images >0.1 deg. [Cartopy](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/index.html) is the new hope for matplotlib users, but I cannot find any example for satellite image tiles.

The frustration is particularly big as this job is super easy with `R`, using the [RGoogleMaps](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RgoogleMaps/index.html) package, e.g.:

```
plotmap(lat, lon, col=palette(value), data=mydataframe, zoom = 17, maptype="satellite")
```

How can we do this in Python?
[image: plot on satellite maps]

Comment: You can use [plotly](https://plot.ly/python/scattermapbox/) with mapbox. You will need a mapbox access token. In the third example in the link just change `style='light'` to `style='satellite'`

Comment: You can access R code in Python Jupyter notebook with the help of `rpy2` package and `%%R` cell magic. See details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008069/r-and-python-in-one-jupyter-notebook

Comment: Below I awarded the bounty and the right answer to Pasa. However, both answers solve the problem in a way, and both would have deserved it. At the same time, there is room for improvement. I would be willing to accept a newer answer and award another bounty to a greater solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An alternative option is to use [`gmplot`](https://github.com/vgm64/gmplot). It is basically a python wrapper around the Google Maps javascript API that allows you to generate `.html` files that render your plots with the map in the background.

Here I use it to plot a random walk against a satellite image background (this map type is not supported by default, but it's pretty straightforward to make it work):

```
from gmplot import GoogleMapPlotter
from random import random

# We subclass this just to change the map type
class CustomGoogleMapPlotter(GoogleMapPlotter):
    def __init__(self, center_lat, center_lng, zoom, apikey='',
                 map_type='satellite'):
        super().__init__(center_lat, center_lng, zoom, apikey)

        self.map_type = map_type
        assert(self.map_type in ['roadmap', 'satellite', 'hybrid', 'terrain'])

    def write_map(self,  f):
        f.write('\t\tvar centerlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(%f, %f);\n' %
                (self.center[0], self.center[1]))
        f.write('\t\tvar myOptions = {\n')
        f.write('\t\t\tzoom: %d,\n' % (self.zoom))
        f.write('\t\t\tcenter: centerlatlng,\n')

        # This is the only line we change
        f.write('\t\t\tmapTypeId: \'{}\'\n'.format(self.map_type))


        f.write('\t\t};\n')
        f.write(
            '\t\tvar map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);\n')
        f.write('\n')

initial_zoom = 16
num_pts = 40

lats = [37.428]
lons = [-122.145]
for pt in range(num_pts):
    lats.append(lats[-1] + (random() - 0.5)/100)
    lons.append(lons[-1] + random()/100)
gmap = CustomGoogleMapPlotter(lats[0], lons[0], initial_zoom,
                              map_type='satellite')
gmap.plot(lats, lons, 'cornflowerblue', edge_width=10)

gmap.draw("mymap.html")
```

You can open the resulting `.html` file in a browser and interact like you would with Google Maps.
Unfortunately, this means you won't get a nice `matplotlib` graph window or anything, so in order to generate an image file you'd need to either take a screenshot yourself or hack something to render the HTML for you.

Another thing to keep in mind is that you will probably need a [Google Maps API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#get-an-api-key), otherwise you will end up with an ugly darkened watermarked map like I did:

[image: Random walk map]

Also, since you want to depict values as colors, you'd need to convert these into color strings by hand and use the `gmap.scatter()` method. If you are interested in this approach let me know so I can try to come up with some code to do that.

### Update

Here is a version that supports encoding values as colors in the scatter plot over the satellite images. To achieve the effect I use `matplotlib`'s colormaps. You can change the colormap if you want, see a list of options [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html). I also included some code to read the API key from the file `apikey.txt`, which allows each of the researchers to use their own individual key without changing the code (if no such file is found, defaults to no API key as usual).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
from gmplot import GoogleMapPlotter
from random import random


class CustomGoogleMapPlotter(GoogleMapPlotter):
    def __init__(self, center_lat, center_lng, zoom, apikey='',
                 map_type='satellite'):
        if apikey == '':
            try:
                with open('apikey.txt', 'r') as apifile:
                    apikey = apifile.readline()
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass
        super().__init__(center_lat, center_lng, zoom, apikey)

        self.map_type = map_type
        assert(self.map_type in ['roadmap', 'satellite', 'hybrid', 'terrain'])

    def write_map(self,  f):
        f.write('\t\tvar centerlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(%f, %f);\n' %
                (self.center[0], self.center[1]))
        f.write('\t\tvar myOptions = {\n')
        f.write('\t\t\tzoom: %d,\n' % (self.zoom))
        f.write('\t\t\tcenter: centerlatlng,\n')

        # Change this line to allow different map types
        f.write('\t\t\tmapTypeId: \'{}\'\n'.format(self.map_type))

        f.write('\t\t};\n')
        f.write(
            '\t\tvar map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);\n')
        f.write('\n')

    def color_scatter(self, lats, lngs, values=None, colormap='coolwarm',
                      size=None, marker=False, s=None, **kwargs):
        def rgb2hex(rgb):
            """ Convert RGBA or RGB to #RRGGBB """
            rgb = list(rgb[0:3]) # remove alpha if present
            rgb = [int(c * 255) for c in rgb]
            hexcolor = '#%02x%02x%02x' % tuple(rgb)
            return hexcolor

        if values is None:
            colors = [None for _ in lats]
        else:
            cmap = plt.get_cmap(colormap)
            norm = Normalize(vmin=min(values), vmax=max(values))
            scalar_map = ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
            colors = [rgb2hex(scalar_map.to_rgba(value)) for value in values]
        for lat, lon, c in zip(lats, lngs, colors):
            self.scatter(lats=[lat], lngs=[lon], c=c, size=size, marker=marker,
                         s=s, **kwargs)


initial_zoom = 12
num_pts = 40

lats = [37.428]
lons = [-122.145]
values = [random() * 20]
for pt in range(num_pts):
    lats.append(lats[-1] + (random() - 0.5)/100)
    lons.append(lons[-1] + random()/100)
    values.append(values[-1] + random())
gmap = CustomGoogleMapPlotter(lats[0], lons[0], initial_zoom,
                              map_type='satellite')
gmap.color_scatter(lats, lons, values, colormap='coolwarm')

gmap.draw("mymap.html")
```

As an example I use a series of monotonically increasing values, which are nicely mapped from a shade of blue to red in the `coolwarm` colormap:

[image: New map example with colors]

Comment: Thank you, the example works very well and it would be great to have an example like above (points and colors)! I am still disappointed by the API Key concept. We are using the maps in scientific research together with hundreds to colleagues to plot and analyze data. It would not make sense to bind the key to a single person when we openly share the scripts with colleagues world-wide. Pay-per-load also does not make sense, because we plot data hundreds of times during the analysis process just to have a quick look... All in all I wonder why `RGoogleMaps` is free-to-use under these conditions..

Comment: I understand the companies charging for the service, as it is probably not cheap to acquire and maintain all those maps. However I agree some use cases should be made free (with low usage for example). Indeed, the pay-per-load scheme is not optimal. I took a look at the R package and it seems to support offline plotting by reusing the map tiles, which is clever.

I've edited my answer to include the option to encode values as colors and an API key file feature to allow different users to use their own private keys.

If any of the answers fits your needs please consider accepting one.

Comment: @pasa I would like to implement something where I click somewhere on the map and it draws a dot (and return the lat long of that dot) instead of giving it the lat long coordinates.  Do you have any idea how to implement this?

Comment: @bakalolo I've never done that before, but I suspect it would not be trivial to return the lat long back into python (if that's what you're asking), since the user interacts with the map in a browser. I suggest you post your own question about this, maybe others can help.

Answer (score 4):

By signing up with Mapbox ([mapbox.com](https://www.mapbox.com)) and using the API key they provide you can get folium to use a custom tileset (their `API_key=` and `tile='Mapbox'` parameters do not seem to work for me).

E.g. this works for me (however the resolution of the publically available maps varies a bit depending on location):

```
import folium

mapboxAccessToken = 'your api key from mapbox'

mapboxTilesetId = 'mapbox.satellite'


m = folium.Map(
    location=[51.4826486,12.7034238],
    zoom_start=16,
    tiles='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/' + mapboxTilesetId + '/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=' + mapboxAccessToken,
    attr='mapbox.com'
)

tooltip = 'Click me!'

folium.Marker([51.482696, 12.703918], popup='<i>Marker 1</i>', tooltip=tooltip).add_to(m)
folium.Marker([51.481696, 12.703818], popup='<b>Marker 2</b>', tooltip=tooltip).add_to(m)

m
```

I have never really used Mapbox, but it looks like you can even create your own tileset if you happen to have images that you would like to use.

NB: I ran this in my notebook install folium first:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install folium
```

In response to the comments:

- Mapbox is a company that provide location and mapping services (as I mentioned, I have never used them, I guess you can find out more at  https://www.mapbox.com)
- Mapbox requires tokens because it is not an unlimited free service...i.e. they give you a token to track requests...and if you use more than is included in the free allocation I guess they throttle your account
- The "v4" is just part of Mapbox's API route. I'm guessing that they also have v1, v2, etc.
- Are there newer versions of the tiles? I'm not sure, I guess you can have a look at Mapbox's documentation. It also looks like you can upload your own maps to Mapbox, and they will store them and serve them back to you.
- How to add the x-/y- axis to the output? I am not really sure. But folium is a wrapper around [LeafletJS](https://leafletjs.com/), which is a popular library with lots of [plugins](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html). It doesn't look too tricky to write a class to wrap any LeafetJS plugin (see out-of-the-box examples [here](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/tree/master/folium/plugins)), so maybe you can find one that suits your issue and wrap it yourself?

Comment: Thank you, the example works. To get the bounty, please elaborate more on the why's and how's: What is Mapbox? Why it requires tokens? Link to potential tiles. What means "v4" in your code and are there newer versions of images (e.g. Landsat)? How to add x- and y axes to the map (like in the question)?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I am unhappy because it looks like a complete mess of additional work und fiddling-around, just to have a satellite map which you can have in R in one line of code. I still hope that there is another solution in python. If not, you'll be assigned the bounty.

Answer (score 4):

Using Bokeh, it could be the most simple way according to me to use the GMAP satellite tile.

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, GMapOptions, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import gmap, figure

output_notebook()

api_key = your_gmap_api_key
```

Your map options

```
map_options = GMapOptions(lat=47.1839600, lng= 6.0014100, map_type="satellite", zoom=8, scale_control=True)
```

Adding some tools to have an interactive map

```
hover=HoverTool(tooltips=[("(x,y)","($x,$y)")])

tools=[hover, 'lasso_select','tap']
```

Creating the map and customize it

```
p = gmap(api_key, map_options, title="your_title", plot_height=600, plot_width=1000, tools=tools)
p.axis.visible = False
p.legend.click_policy='hide'
```

Adding your Data

```
your_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(lat=your_df.lat, lon=your_df.lon, size = your_df.value))

p.circle(x="lon",y="lat",size=size, fill_color="purple",legend = "your_legend", fill_alpha=0.2, line_alpha=0, source=your_source)
show(p)
```