# How to use jupyter notebook with multiple columns and multiple languages

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, stata

I'd like to run a jupyter notebook that can run multiple languages (one in each column) to show how to run simple things in each respective languages (r, python, stata). Is there such extension to do so?

Answer (score 3):

To use R and Stata code alongside your Python code in the same Jupyter notebook, you need to install IPYStata for Stata and rpy2 for R.

Install [IPYStata](https://pypi.org/project/ipystata/) with `pip install ipystata` and use it with the `%%stata` magic:

```
In[1]: import ipystata  
In[2]: %%stata  
display "Hello, I am printed in Stata."
```

Install [rpy2](https://pypi.org/project/rpy2/) with `pip install rpy2` and import `robjects`:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
pi = robjects.r['pi']
pi[0]
```

Check [the documentation](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/index.html) and see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008069/r-and-python-in-one-jupyter-notebook) for more details

Alternatively, if you want to run Stata code in separate Jupyter notebooks, you can use [stata_kernel](https://pypi.org/project/stata-kernel/)