# How to read R dataframe as a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, r, pandas, geometry, rpy2

I am executing the R code in python using `rpy2` library where I was able to achieve a data frame that I wanted. The dataframe has column with geometry, now I am trying to read the created R dataframe as Pandas dataframe using `ro.conversion.rpy2py`, but when I try to do the same it is giving an empty data frame like below.

How do I convert R data frame with geometry column as an pandas data frame/ geo pandas data frame?

Code:-

```py
from rpy2 import robjects
import rpy2.robjects as ro
robjects.r(''' 
  library(osrm)
  iso <- osrmIsochrone(loc = c(12.0878, 55.6419),
                       breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 60, length.out = 2), res = 50)
  print(iso)''')
```

output:-

```
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 3 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 11.10805 ymin: 55.02879 xmax: 13.14378 ymax: 56.08983
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
  id isomin isomax                       geometry
1  1      0     60 MULTIPOLYGON (((12.54979 56...
```

#converting R dataframe to python data frame

```py
r_mat = robjects.globalenv['iso']
pd_dt = ro.conversion.rpy2py(r_mat)
pd_dt
```

Output:-

```
R/rpy2 DataFrame (1 x 4)
id  isomin  isomax  geometry
... ... ... ...
```

[image]

Comment: Had to scroll to the bottom, but have you tried this way? -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56310926/6509519